Backtrader - multiple time series with different lengths
I have historical stock data from Norgate that I'd like to use with Backtrader. Of course, the stocks that I'd like to use all have different start and end dates that they've been listed. When I try to perform a historic backtest, Backtrader seems to only run for min and max date common to ALL of the stocks in the test. This seems to be compltely contrary to testing for survivorship bias.
Am I understanding this limitation correctly? Is there anything I can do to "fix" the data or my backtest to acoomodate? Thanks
